# Aptio 2.22 @Asus PN52 - how to enable boot from usb stick and install Linux?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, secure-boot

I am trying to install Linux Mint 20.3 from USB stick on my new Asus PN52. USB stick was made with UNetbootin on Linux Mint 19. USB drive and internal NVMe disk - operating system destination - are visible.
[image]

Once I hit F8 and enter boot menu - it is empty:
[image]

There are no options in Boot menu in Aptio to add drives to boot sequence:
[image]

Secure boot option is disabled.
Fast boot option is disabled.

How to force Aptio to boot from USB?

Comment: How did you made the USB live/installer? Which distro? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: I would use `dd` to write the iso file directly to the USB device, rather than "unetbootn". There may be other options in BIOS to enable/disable boot devices. (Have you ever booted from USB before?) and you may have to try another USB port as BIOS may only support USB1/2 and you may be plugged into a USB3...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with USB stick not with the new computer.